# Can I use Visual Studio as an IDE for cocos2d-x 3.0rc2, c++ development?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

So I plan on building for Android with cocos2d-x 3.0rc2 and there isn't a whole lot of updated documentation on what all I'm supposed to do to get up and running. I have the whole environment set up already. I can run tests and make some basic sprites just by editing the C++ files in Notepad++, however I need to get to a point where I am actually set up in an IDE. There are tutorials of importing projects into ADT, which I have gotten to run but I cannot edit the *.cpp files from inside eclipse. Is that how I'm supposed to set up my environment? Do people usually just edit in a basic text editor and run from command line or is there something I'm missing.

I also opened up the Visual Studio solution that comes with a new project and inside that I have auto completion and it's a nice environment, but there is still the hassle with makefiles that I just can't get working. I tried using some of the extended features and using CocoStudio exports in my projects and the compiler won't have any of that. Is there just a lack of documentation for people who are not comfortable developing for Android already?

When I make a new class, or use a new include, do I have to manually add that that to a makefile? If so, where is somewhere that I can learn how that process works and be able to apply it to new situations?

I feel lost because I'm not too used to getting into all the 'nitty-gritty' bits of development.

If someone wants to help me out understanding all this, I would be immensely appreciative.

Thanks,
Vynlar

Comment: yes it works with VS. Not an answer but it's a well known fact that cocos2dx isn't the easiest engine to get set up and working. If it annoys you too much one option is certainly to look into alternatives (Unity, libgdx, cocos2d-iphone, and many more). Perhaps even a gamemaking tool like Game Maker or GameSalad would be suitable dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 is supported. Here is documentation on setting up Cocos2d-x v3.0 with Visual Studio:  http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Windows

Comment: This link shows how to compile for windows, so the question is still: is it possible to compile for android with visual studio ;)

Answer (score 0):

This question is like two years old, but if anyone hits it in search results there is now a Visual Studio project to target Android devices with Cocos2d-x. It's not integrated with the cocos template system, so it currently needs to be updated per cocos version. Currently it's for VS 2015 Update 3 and Cocos 3.12.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/12/cocos2d-x-visual-studio-android-project/

I was the developer on this, so I can be contacted with any questions.